# Synchronize AVPlayer with timer on iOS

Tags: ios, avfoundation, core-animation, grand-central-dispatch, avplayer

I'm creating something like animation with video played in AVPlayer and timer. To do it correctly, I need to synchronise AVPlayer with timer. So if video duration is for example 5s duration, I run the timer for 5s (with any time interval, e.g. 1./30.s, what is 30 frames per second) and I'd like the video to be played for exactly the same time.
But the video (e.g. 5s MOV file) plays in AVPlayer for about 5.2s-5.3s. It's too big desynchronisation in my case (for 30fps it is about 6-9 frames). This desynchronisation is probably mostly from a delay, which occurs when starting to play the video.

Here is some code:

1. Custom player view:

```
@interface AVVideoPlayerView : UIView
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVPlayer *player;
@end

@implementation AVVideoPlayerView
+ (Class)layerClass {
    return [AVPlayerLayer class];
}
- (AVPlayer *)player {
    return (AVPlayer *)((AVPlayerLayer *)self.layer).player;
}
- (void)setPlayer:(AVPlayer *)player {
    ((AVPlayerLayer *)self.layer).player = player;
}
@end
```

2. Create and load local video URL:

```
    NSURL *videoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"testVideo" withExtension:@"mov"];
    AVURLAsset *videoAsset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:videoURL];
    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:videoAsset automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys:@[@"duration"]];
    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    player.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = NO;

    CGRect frame = ...;

    self.playerView = [[AVVideoPlayerView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    self.playerView.player = player;
    self.playerView.player.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:self.playerView];
```

3. Wait for the video to be ready to play:

```
    [playerItem addObserver:self
                 forKeyPath:@"status"
                    options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial
                    context:nil];

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{

    if ([object isKindOfClass:[AVPlayerItem class]] && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {

        AVPlayerItem *playerItem = object;

        if (playerItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay) {
            //play the video and start timer
        }
    }
```

4. Run the GCD timer and start playing the video at the same time

```
    CGFloat duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.playerView.player.currentItem.duration);

    CGFloat timeInterval = 1./30.;

    //all predicted iterations count
    self.allIterations = round(duration / timeInterval);

    //create and fire the timer

    self.timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, dispatch_get_main_queue());

    dispatch_source_set_timer(self.timer, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, timeInterval * NSEC_PER_SEC), timeInterval * NSEC_PER_SEC, 0);

    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(self.timer, ^{

        self.iterationsCount++;

        if (self.iterationsCount == self.allIterations) {

            //!!! here I'd like the player currentTime to be equal the duration of the video (or very close to it)


        }
    });

    dispatch_resume(self.timer);

    //play the video
    [self.playerView.player playImmediatelyAtRate:1];
```

Is there any way to synchronise AVPlayer current time with GCD timer? It would be best for me if desynchronisation is max 1 frame (1/30s).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: i think you should use 60 fps.

Comment: Why? FPS is not the problem here, it could be 10, 20, 30, 60 or any other. I think the problem is with AVPlayer and timer synchronisation - video player has a delay in comparison to the timer.

Comment: so u can change the time interval to 1 seconds so that it repeats by one second and end it at 5 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's not bad idea I think. But I need exactly 30 or 60 fps, which is similar to most of videos fps.

Comment: So this idea cannot help me. I think this is the moment, where AVFoundation possibilities are limited.